# Creating an object in the constructor or an init function

Tags: c++, class

I have defined a class like this:

```
 class CircularBuffer {
   private:
     struct entry {
       uint64_t key;
       int nextPtr;
       int prevPtr;
       int delta;
     };

     int head, tail, limit, degree;
     entry *en;
   public:
     CircularBuffer(int a, int b)
     {
       limit = a;
       head = 0;
       tail = limit -1;
       degree = b;
       en = new entry[ limit ];
       for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) {
         en[i].key = 0;
         en[i].delta = 0;
         en[i].nextPtr = 0;
         en[i].prevPtr = 0;
       }
     };
     ~CircularBuffer() { delete [] en; }
  };
```

And in another file I have included this class (the header file)

```
 #include "circular.h"
 class foo {
    CircularBuffer cb;
    foo() {}   //ERROR LINE
    void initialize() {
       cb = new CircularBuffer(10, 2);
    }
 };
```

However this has error which says:

```
 error: no matching function for call to ‘CircularBuffer::CircularBuffer()’
 note: candidates are: CircularBuffer::CircularBuffer(int, int)
 note:                 CircularBuffer::CircularBuffer(const CircularBuffer&)
```

and it forces me to do like this:

```
 #include "circular.h"
 class foo {
    CircularBuffer cb;
    foo()
      : cb( CircularBuffer(10, 2) )
    {}

    void initialize() {}
 };
```

However I don't want the second implementation. I want the first one. How can I fix that?

Comment: what is the error message

Comment: @mahmood: Your buffer class provokes memory leaks and double deletions, and I am really not sure why you don't want to use initialization, but rather taint your code with arbitrary default constructors.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the point! can you explain more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a default constructor

```
CircularBuffer()
{
    // set a and b to default values
}
```

Comment: So how can I pass the numbers!?

Comment: Constructors have no return type, so there are no "void constructor"s.

Comment: constructor with a void parameter list, im _not_ a noob

Comment: Whew, who said you are a noob? However, "default constructor" is the correct wording. But I don't advise on using one if it doesn't make sense for a class to have a default vakue.

Comment: @phresnel, thats right, but an null pointer is also no alternative

Comment: @Quonux: In the general case: Indeed. In some special cases, where lazy initialization or optional values are needed, using smart pointers is more clean than blindly introducing default constructors. In this question, initialization is the only true solution. (sidenote: using the term `C/C++` is misleading, those are different languages with different idioms)

Answer (score 0):

This should be possible

```
#include "circular.h"
class foo {
    CircularBuffer cb;
    foo() {}
    void initialize() {
        cb = CircularBuffer(10, 2);
    }
};
```

The problem with your version was that you were using `new`, which returns a pointer, but the member variable `cb` is not a pointer.

However, the best way would be

```
#include "circular.h"
class foo {
    CircularBuffer cb;
    foo() : cb(10,  2) {}
};
```

Or, if you want to pass parameters to the constructor

```
#include "circular.h"
class foo {
    CircularBuffer cb;
    foo(int a, int b) : cb(a,  b) {}
};
```

Comment: Yeah I know that but this implementation is hard to parametrize

Comment: @Zyx 2000: Not possible, because `CircularBuffer` has no default constructor.

Comment: @mahmood I don't understand exactly what you bean by parametrizing in this case, because I don't see how it is hard. I edited my answer to give you an example of how to do it.

Comment: @Zyx 2000: I mean `foo() : cb(X,  Y) {}` and setting X and Y form another function, command line ....

Answer (score 0):

> and it forces me to do like this:
>
> ```
> ...
> foo()
>   : cb( CircularBuffer(10, 2) )
> {}
> ...
> ```
>
> However I don't want the second implementation. I want the first one. How can I fix that?

It does not force you to this, but rather to this:

```
: cb(10, 2)
```

And this is how you initialize in C++. Everything  coming after the opening `{` is assignment, not initialization.

The "fix" is to use initialization rather than assignment for initialization. There's not much to love or hate about, this is C++.

Answer (score 0):

Just define `cb` as a pointer

```
#include "circular.h"
 class foo {
    CircularBuffer * cb;
    foo() {}   //ERROR LINE
    void initialize() {
       cb = new CircularBuffer(10, 2);
    }
 };
```

And don't forget to `delete cb;` somewhere to not leak your memory

Comment: Just as a pointer, et voila, it became an exception-unsafe and leaking class that totally ignores the rule of three/five.

Answer (score -1):

It gives you an error because cb is not a pointer and you are using "new".

But BTW... the constructor initialization is more efficient :D

Comment: But it is hard to parametrzie