# Valgrind complains about a memory leak but I'm calling new and delete

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have used pointers to create an array and then wrote a delete procedure in the destructor

```
class cBuffer{
  private:
    struct entry {
      uint64_t key;
      uint64_t pc;
    };
    entry *en;
  public:
    cBuffer(int a, int b, int mode)
    {
      limit = a;
      dist = b;
      md = mode;
      en = new entry[ limit ];
      for (int i=0; i<limit; i++) {
        en[i].key = 0;
        en[i].pc = 0;
      }
    };
    ~cBuffer() { delete [] en; }
    ...
   }
```

In another class I use cBuffer like this:

```
class foo() {
   cBuffer *buf;
   foo()
   {
     buf = new cBuffer(gSize, oDist, Mode);
   }
};
```

However, valgrind complains about the new operator

```
==20381== 16,906,240 bytes in 32 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 11,217 of 11,221
==20381==    at 0x4A0674C: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:305)
==20381==    by 0x166D92F8: cBuffer::cBuffer(int, int, int)
```

Comment: You did not follow the Rule of three.

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)

Comment: @mahmood: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722); if you're managing a resource and releasing it in the destructor, then you almost certainly need to implement or delete the copy constructor and copy-assignment operator, otherwise you can end up with two objects both trying to release the same resource.

Comment: But that's unlikely to be the cause of a memory leak; how are you creating and destroying the `cBuffer` object? My best guess is that you're leaking the whole object with a `new cBuffer` and no corresponding `delete`.

Comment: You're using naked pointers. You shouldn't.

Comment: @mahmood: and what happens when `foo` is destroyed?

Comment: Why are you storing the `cBuffer` on the free store?

Comment: @Mat: I understand that you may say I have to include `delete buf` in `~foo()`. But does that really matters? If that is the case, valgrind should point there and not the cBuffer itself

Comment: @mahmood: I would expect valgrind to report both leaks. Are you saying it only reports that one?

Comment: @Mike Seymour: Yes you are right. I scrolled one by one and saw cBuffer first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 cBuffer *buf;
   foo()
   {
     buf = new cBuffer(gSize, oDist, Mode);
   }
```

You need to call

```
delete buf;
```

Since you explicitly called `new`

Answer (score 1):

Your `class foo` will cause your leak, since you never delete the dynamically allocated `cBuffer`. The solution is simple: there's no need for dynamic allocation at all here.

```
class foo {
    cBuffer buf;  // An object, not a pointer
    foo() : buf(gSize, oDist, Mode) {}
};
```

More generally, when you do need dynamic allocation, be careful that you always `delete` what you `new`. The most reliable way to do this is to use RAII types such as containers and smart pointers to manage all dynamic resources for you.

Comment: The reason why I used pointers is discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15922760/creating-an-object-in-the-constructor-or-an-init-function

Comment: @mahmood: I don't see any discussion of pointers there, just some bad advice telling you to use a pointer when you don't need to, and some better advice telling you not to.